# How to get correct file size after resizing an image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, resize, filesize

I have this code:

```
// Build the path where I want to save the file;
$filePath="uploads/image.jpeg";
/*
 * Open an input stream relative to $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] 
 * and write it in an output stream relative to $filePath;
 */
writeFile($filePath);

echo "Before resizing: ".filesize($filePath)." bytes";

/*
 * Create a resized version of the image using imagecopyresampled();
 */
$imageResized = resizeImage($filePath);
/*
 * Actually write the image to the same location of the original;
 */
imagejpeg($imageResized, $filePath);

echo "After resizing: ".filesize($filePath)." bytes";
```

Now the fact is that the ehoes give me the same exact filesize, while actually in the file explorer the filesize after resizing is much lower!
How do I get the correct file size after resizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the manual on filesize:

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.

So use a `clearstatcache()` before the second filesize call

Comment: Thank you it worked! I overlooked that note on the php manual.
Plus I used `stats($filePath)` insead of `filesize($filePath)` to get the file size.